# Problem launching Whatsapp from flutter on IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, whatsapp, flutter-dependencies

Sending message through whatsapp in Flutter is not working on IOS. It works fine on Android but on IOS whatsapp is not launching. I tried 3 different ways but unsuccessful in all of them.

In Runner Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

**1)** First I tried this way to send message via message

```
var whatsappUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=$phone&text=$message";
  if (await canLaunch(whatsappUrl)) {
    await launch(whatsappUrl);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $whatsappUrl';
  }
```

But it gives an exception on launching whatsapp

[image]

**2)** Second way I tried is found from this [link](https://medium.com/@omer5549910000/launch-whatsapp-using-flutter-app-856b8e35f5d9) this but it giving an error that page not found

```
String url() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
     return "whatsapp://wa.me/$phone/?text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
  } else {
     return "whatsapp://send?   phone=$phone&text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
  }
}

if (await canLaunch(url())) {
   await launch(url());
} else {
   throw 'Could not launch ${url()}';
}
```

**3)** last I tried to call whatsapp url

```
String message = 'Hi, I see your Ad on Yallamotor and I am interested in your car '+title;
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  await launch("https://wa.me/${phone}?text=${Uri.parse(message)}");
}
```

but it gives error on whatsapp like we couldn't find the page you are looking for

[image]

Comment: Did you check Phone number? It shouldn't contian special characters.

Comment: Refer WhatsApp docs for [iOS](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app), [Android](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/im-an-android-developer-how-can-i-integrate-whatsapp-with-my-app).

Comment: @LalKrishna phone is +9233645XXXX . Do you think + is the issue?

Comment: Yes. It should be like: (country code)(number). Ex. 9233645xxxx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatsapp supports Universal URLs on iOS devices.

The format is:

```
https://wa.me/<number>?text=<urlencodedtext>
```

Examples:

```
Use: https://wa.me/15551234567

Don't use: https://wa.me/+001-(555)1234567
```

Probably you are calling this URL with incorrect format in number.

Refer Whatsapp FAQ for [iOS](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app), [Android](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/im-an-android-developer-how-can-i-integrate-whatsapp-with-my-app).

Answer (score 0):

By default, launchUrl mode is `LaunchMode.platformDefault` which will open webview, if you want to open installed app change it to `LaunchMode.externalApplication`.

```
if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
   await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
} else {
   throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```